# Error is not intercepted by try catch block

Tags: php, laravel, exception, error-handling, runtime-error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
(tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in
/vendor/symfony/debug/Exception/FatalErrorException.php on line 1  PHP Stack trace:
```

I get the following error which is not intercepted in a try catch block.

```
use \Exception as Exception;

try {
   $this->recursiveCall();
} catch (ErrorException $ex) {
    exit;
}catch (Exception $ex) {
    exit;
}
```

If raise to `memory_limit = 512M` in php.ini it works fine but what bothers me is that error is not handled.

I've read that you can write your own php error callback but I'm afraid that Laravel error handling might depend on that.

Any ideas how to handle the issue? 10x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Catch does not work for Fatal errors. You can use try-catch for exceptions but fatal errors actually "break" your program you can not simple catch them, you have to solve them. Not that the exceptions-warnings shouldn't be solved but they are not as critical as Fatal errors.

The solution i see is either optimize your query (maybe add a limit could help) or you increase the memory size as you suggested.

This error generally comes from "too much data processing" so either you narrow down the data to make your script run faster or you increase the limit.